# How to view HTML file in Partial View of ASP.NET MVC (not Razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application in which I have created a partial view as below:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

and my parent view has the following code:

```
<div>
       <% @Html.RenderPartial("ViewerControl"); %> 
    </div>
```

Now, I want to open an HTML file in the partial view. I am not sure how to do it. Quick sample code will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about opening the HTML file? I don't really get what you are trying to do..

Comment: I have an html file in my Contents folder. I want to open it on a partial view after the parent view buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Views do not support server side include directives or similar. Your best bet would be to create an action result that returns the markup as a ContentResult.

```
public ContentResult HtmlFile() {
    return Content(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("Give the path here")));
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<%: Html.Raw(Html.Action("HtmlFile")) %>
```

Totally off the cuff, but you get the point: invoke a server side action to retrieve your markup, or alternatively deliver it via the Model on the previous Action Result execution.